# Trigger Test Class failing assertion

Tags: trigger, failing-tests

For the following class, I have a test class with two methods. The second method is failing at System.assert(`Jet2.Status__c == 'Booked'`). The status is still 'Active.' How do I fix this?

**Trigger**

```
trigger ReservationTrigger on Reservation__c (after insert, after update) {

    Set<Id> JetIds = new Set <Id>();
    List<Jet__c> JetsToSave = new List<Jet__c>();
    List<APEX_Invoice__c> invoicesToSave = new List<APEX_Invoice__c>();
    Map<Id, Jet__c> Jets = new Map<Id, Jet__c>();

    //Go through and if we find the reservation that is marked as Paid,
    //Then make the Jet booked
    //

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){

        for(Reservation__c res: Trigger.new){
            if(res.paid__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(res.id).paid__c && res.paid__c == true){
                JetIds.add(res.Jet__c);
            }
        }

        if(!JetIds.isEmpty()){
            for(Jet__c Jet: [select id,Status__c from Jet__c where id in : JetIds]){
                Jet.Status__c = 'Booked';
                JetsToSave.add(Jet);
            }

            update JetsToSave;
        }   
    }

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        //Go through the list of reservations and get all of the related jets
        for(Reservation__c Res: Trigger.New){
            Jets.put (Res.Jet__c, null);
        }

        //Now go through the list of jets and add the data into the map
        for(Jet__c Jet: [select Id, Base_Cost__c, Cost_Per_Nautical_Mile__c from Jet__c where Id in :Jets.keySet()]){
            Jets.put (Jet.id, Jet);
        }

        //Go through the list of reservations and create the invoices to write
        for(Reservation__c Res: Trigger.New){

            //Which jet are we using for this reservation
            Jet__c Jet = Jets.get(Res.Jet__c);
            Decimal TotalAmount = Jet.Base_Cost__c + Jet.Cost_Per_Nautical_Mile__c * Res.Nautical_Miles__c;
            APEX_Invoice__c Inv = new APEX_Invoice__c();
            Inv.APEX_Customer__c = Res.APEX_Customer__c;
            Inv.Reservation__c = Res.Id;
            Inv.APEX_Amount_Paid__c = TotalAmount;

            invoicesToSave.add(Inv);
        }
        insert invoicesToSave;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class ReservationTriggerTestClass {

    static testMethod void testCreateInvoices(){

        Jet__c Jet = new Jet__c(Name                      = 'TestJet1',
                                Base_Cost__c              = 1000,
                                Cost_per_Nautical_Mile__c = 10,
                                Status__c                 = 'Active');

        APEX_Customer__c Cus = new APEX_Customer__c(Name = 'TestCustomer');

        insert Jet;
        insert Cus;

        Reservation__c Res = new Reservation__c(Jet__c            = Jet.id,
                                                APEX_Customer__c  = Cus.id,
                                                Nautical_Miles__c = 50,
                                                Paid__c           = false);


        Test.startTest();
        insert Res;
        Test.stopTest();

        //Check that the invoice was created and the related to the right records
        //

        APEX_Invoice__c Invoice = [select id, Reservation__c, APEX_Customer__c, APEX_Amount_Paid__c
                              from APEX_Invoice__c
                              where APEX_Customer__c = :Cus.Id
                              and Reservation__c = :Res.id];

        System.assert(Invoice.APEX_Amount_Paid__c == 1500);

    }

    static testMethod void testUpdateReservation(){

        Jet__c Jet2 = new Jet__c(Name                     = 'TestJet2',
                                Base_Cost__c              = 1000,
                                Cost_per_Nautical_Mile__c = 10,
                                Status__c                 = 'Active');

        APEX_Customer__c Cus = new APEX_Customer__c(Name = 'TestCustomer2');

        insert Jet2;
        insert Cus;

        Reservation__c Res = new Reservation__c(Jet__c            = Jet2.id,
                                                APEX_Customer__c  = Cus.id,
                                                Nautical_Miles__c = 50,
                                                Paid__c           = false);

        Test.startTest();

        insert Res;
        Jet2 = [select id, status__c from Jet__c where Id = :Jet2.id];
        System.assert(Jet2.Status__c == 'Active');
        Res.Paid__c = true;
        update Res;
        System.assert(Jet2.Status__c == 'Booked');

        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please use `system.assertEquals(expected, actual, message)`. You will get much clearer failure messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DML operations like the `update` you perform in the code that's being tested have no effect on sObject instances already in memory, except for the population of the `Id` field on sObjects that are inserted.

```
    Res.Paid__c = true;
    update Res;
    System.assert(Jet2.Status__c == 'Booked');
```

Your reference to `Jet2` here is stale: it was queried prior to the `update` operation. You need to re-query it as you do above:

```
    Jet2 = [select id, status__c from Jet__c where Id = :Jet2.id];
```

to obtain any changes effected by the trigger.